# How many movies belong to only one genre?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I want to find how many movies have only one genre?
This the SQL code I have used

```
WITH genre_count 
AS
(
SELECT
    COUNT(movie_id) AS no_of_movies_with_one_genre
FROM
    genre
)
SELECT *
FROM
    genre_count
HAVING
    COUNT(genre) = 1;
```

Below is the ERD of my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98XBJ.jpg)

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that data, and your attempts to resolve the problem. What exactly is not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_movies_with_one_genre
FROM genre g1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM genre g2 WHERE g2.movie_id = g1.movie_id AND g2.genre <> g1.genre)
```

Comment: Thanks for the query

Comment: @JayThakur fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification needed in your code, see if this works

```
WITH genre_count 
AS(
SELECT movie_id, count(genre) as count_of_genre
FROM genre group by movie_id)
SELECT count(movie_id) FROM genre_count where count_of_genre = 1;
```